# Linear Equations for competitive exam

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from an aptitude exam conducted in India for admission into post graduate management programs of the Indian Institutes of Management (IIMs).

A school allows either all white uniform or a combination uniform where one of the trouser or shirt is black and the other is white. In all there are 15 combination uniforms, 12 white trousers and 13 white shirts. What is the total number of students in the school?
A) 20
B) 25
C) 30
D) None of these

## LinearEquation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $a$ be the number of students with white shirt and black trousers, $b$ be the number of students with black shirt and white trousers and $c$ be the number of students with white shirt and white trousers.

Then you are told that

$a+b=15\\a+c=13\\b+c=12$

and you need to find the total number of students in the school, which is $a+b+c$.